# No matching function for call Error using boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am trying to write a parallel bubblesort function. I am running into an error when using boost::bind:

```
void swap(vector<int>& input, int i, int j)
{
    if (input[i] > input[j])
    {   
        int temp = input[j];
        input[j] = input[i];
        input[i] = temp;
    }   
    return;
}

void parallel_bubblesort(vector<int>& input, int, int)
{

    int i, j, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {   
        boost::asio::io_service ioService;
        boost::thread_group threadpool;
        for (j = 0; j < input.size() - 1; j++)
        {   
            ioService.post(boost::bind(&swap, boost::ref(input), 2 * j + i % 2, 2 * j + 1 + i % 2));
        }   

        for (int t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
        {   
            threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
        }   

        threadpool.join_all();
        ioService.stop();
    }   
    return;
}
```

It snags on the line

```
ioService.post(boost::bind(&swap, boost::ref(input), 2 * j + i % 2, 2 * j + 1 + i % 2));
```

The error says

```
no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int)’
```

This seems weird, because none of these are overloaded at all, does anybody know what this means?

Edit: Here is the full program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::this_thread;

int check_solution(const vector<int>&);
void bubblesort(vector<int>&);
void swap1(vector<int>&, int, int);
void parallel_bubblesort(vector<int>&);

int main()
{
    string line, token;
    string file = "test.txt";
    vector<int> unsorted_integers;

    //print out filename
    cout << file << endl;

    ifstream myfile(file);

    //open file
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {   
        //load everything into a vector
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {   
            int temp;
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            std::getline(ss, token, '\n');
            temp = atoi(token.c_str());
            unsorted_integers.push_back(temp);
        }   
    }   

    vector<int> unsorted_integers2(unsorted_integers);
 //starts clock
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //run the sort function and check for correctness
    parallel_bubblesort(unsorted_integers2);
    if(check_solution(unsorted_integers2))
    {
        cout << "The parallel sort solution is correct" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The parallel sort solution is incorrect" << endl;
    }

    //stops clock and prints times
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> total_time2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(end2 - start2);
    cout << "The parallel sort function took " << total_time2.count() << " seconds." << endl;

    return 0;
}


void swap1(vector<int>& input, int i, int j)
{
    if (input[i] > input[j])
    {
        int temp = input[j];
        input[j] = input[i];
        input[i] = temp;
    }
    return;
}

void parallel_bubblesort(vector<int>& input, int, int)
{

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
      {
        boost::asio::io_service ioService;
        boost::thread_group threadpool;
        for (j = 0; j < input.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            ioService.post(boost::bind(&swap1, boost::ref(input), 2 * j + i % 2, 2 * j + 1 + i % 2));
        }

        for (int t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
        {
            threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
        }

        threadpool.join_all();
        ioService.stop();
    }
    return;
}

int check_solution(const vector<int>& solution)
{
    vector<int> correct_solution(solution);
    std::sort(correct_solution.begin(), correct_solution.end());
    return (solution == correct_solution);
}
```

Comment: What compiler and boost version are you using? VC12 with Boost 1.55 has no problem compiling this. You could also may be missing an `include`, it may help if you provided a ready to try snippet with your `include`s.

Comment: I am using the command g++ bubblesort.cpp -std = c++0x -boost_thread-mt -lboost_system

Comment: Add -Wall -Werror to your compilation line.

Comment: Oh cool trick, this seems promising this was the output:
bubblesort.cpp: In function ‘void bubblesort(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’:
bubblesort.cpp:94: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
bubblesort.cpp:96: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
bubblesort.cpp:92: error: unused variable ‘temp’
bubblesort.cpp: In function ‘void parallel_bubblesort(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int, int)’:
bubblesort.cpp:120: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

Comment: Actually, yeah these warnings don't seem related to the problem

Comment: Your current code builds just fine, with only 2 warnings. gcc 4.8.2.1, boost 1.54. `g++ -c -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -g -gdwarf-2 -D_DEBUG bubblesort.cpp`

Comment: Cool, this is compiling now thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: So what have you done to make it build finally?

Comment: I am not exactly sure.....my environment doesn't recognize the -std=c++11 flag and none of the others seem like they should be affecting anything, maybe one of my old compiler flags was messing something up?

Comment: Anyways I would advise you to mark John's reply as an answer because he has correctly identified the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably doing `using namespace std;` somewhere, and `std::swap` is a thing.  I suggest you simply rename your `swap` function to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but changing that didn't fix the issue

Comment: Actually this *is* the problem. Try renaming the function `swap()` to something else.

Comment: I have just removed `using namespace std;` and explicitly referenced `std::vectors` and the error is gone.

Comment: I renamed swap and it didn't help

Comment: Ok we are probably on different pages with the code at the moment. Can you create a minimal snippet from your current code that shows the error?

Comment: I edited my main comment to include all the relevant parts of code